Structure of ～から～と
From 16 bit sensation chapter 3 column,

本作で『同級生』について書いているが、この大ヒットは、エロゲーから美少女ゲームへの転換を大きく進めたと言える。それはつまり、「エロがメインで、そのための存在としてのヒロイン」から、「ヒロインと主人公との関係性や感情、物語を紡ぐことによってたどり着く恋愛描写、そしてエロ」とゲーム内の序列が転換したことに他ならない。

I wonder if there is any difference between ～から～に and ～から～と. Perhaps in the former, と is quotative and ～から～ is the quoted text.

You're almost correct, but the particle choice of the original text seems a little unnatural to me.

AからBに転換する: Common and standard.
AからBへ転換する: Common and standard.
AからBへと転換する: This is also common. This と is this, and takes "AからBへ" as a set. So this phrase is structurally more like "to shift in a from-A-to-B manner".
AからBと転換する: へ has been omitted from 3. This is understandable, and is probably acceptable in speech, but sounds awkward in a formal essay to me.

